# Backup SharePoint Online add-in data

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, backup

We are maintaining a SharePoint Online site with several custom add-ins(apps). We need to be able to backup the data stored in the SharePoint Online lists of the add-ins.

We have considered recommended third-party solutions such as Metalogix, CloudAlly and AvePoint, but none of these provide functionality for backing up add-in data.

A last resort would be to write our own backup application using the SharePoint Online API. This however is a solution inconvenient to maintain, because when changes are done to the data-structure of the add-ins, changes also need to be done in the backup application.

Do anyone have a suggestion for a good solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If the application is storing the content in SharePoint lists and libraries for example in the "appdata" subsite created when you deploy an app the AvePoint solution should be able to back it up. I know it can't when the app is sitting externally on something like Azure or AWS but otherwise there should be a way. The application can also help deploy changes to apps when you need to publish new versions in bulk across your O365 environment. Hopefully this helps from a 3rd party tool perspective.

The latest updates in the SP Framework will be super useful if you go with building a custom solution as well: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki